# Iterating over a parameter pack of structured templates

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates

I'd like to be able to pass a variadic function a number of structured templates (representing sensor readings) and have it iterate over the members of those structs. My template and initializers look like this:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct reading_t {
    const char *name;
    const char *fmt;
    const char *units;

    T value;
};

static reading_t<float> longitude = {"Longitude", "%f", "deg", 0.0};
static reading_t<uint32_t> altitude = {"Altitude", "%d", "m", 0};
static reading_t<float> heading = {"Heading", "%f", "deg", 0};
```

My ultimate goal is just a function that spits out a concatenated list of `reading_t.name` so coming from C I started out with a typical variadic function that looked like this without luck:

```cpp
char *concat_readings(char *b, reading_t<auto> *reading...) {
va_list args;
...
}

char buffer[256] = "";
concat_readings(&buffer, &longitude, &altitude, &latitude NULL);

// out << buffer; // Longitude, Altitude, Heading
```

Now I'm lost in the soup of C++ parameter packs, etc.

PS: I'm on an embedded system so access to the Standard library isn't an option unfortunately.

Comment: A C++ implementation must have a C++ library available. Without the C++ library there is no iostreams, no overloaded formatted output operators. If all you have is the C library you might as well keep this in C.

Comment: but how do you want to use a single `reading_t` object?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik template metaprogramming does not require standard library. Everything which is a language feature and does not require a standard library header will be available on embedded systems, this is _not_ a reason to "might as well keep this in C".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly and you want to concatenate names of readings using parameter pack inside concat_readings, then you can do next.

You can use no standard library includes at all, just implement your own string management functions like strcat/strcpy. In fact you can use fully working C++ features with templates on embedded systems, without including even single standard library header, I did this way on my very large embedded project. Templates and other features of C++ don't need any standard headers. Maybe you also want to disable exceptions in GCC with `-fno-exceptions`, exceptions are not needed for C++ features if you don't use exceptions at all.

I used strcpy/strcat/printf just for example, you have to use and implement your versions of these functions yourself.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVNNa4QwEL3nV4QtW7RYWba0F7dCbz30tHgrZUnjxwZiFJ0UyuJvtxONH9u1pVCRmDxn3nszjrwsb7lkKmvbK6G41HFCd7yGWBQhOUMqobJvUCwUhIRAkpeSAWLwWSaK5QmNQoIZmgOtEoZh2QHoiVC8eKFqoPzIKnpjQoMLNM3hEtRKQB2QDo/oB5MaM5tgUXwfkj7JMHAGB@uhdiz8rlNvMrbbh1bqegBdaxZrwHxnHu8bCbc3WCWgK2Xo0MuyFY@Oe9/36T76tzevk@7lx6hoCjMyA@kf65i/XuHtjv0/czhPr1FmuQs4EzRnQjmTOAPBZ25TWTAIqSxUJsDM0iM9rV6GkzGwTs0aJxk@Nv6mCZaJNGrdbQ/IxSRMVE/20DHFZs0Nz08s1s6xBzqG535/YaWxE9h9Kyz4dXv/8GYyml86NtbpjTa9Qc22sMSfC1Jnta5RBZNc08m2/QI)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdint>

template <typename T>
struct reading_t {
    const char *name;
    const char *fmt;
    const char *units;

    T value;
};

template <typename R>
char * concat_readings(char * buf, reading_t<R> const & reading) {
    strcat(buf, reading.name);
    return buf;
}

template <typename R, typename ... RT>
char * concat_readings(char * buf, reading_t<R> const & reading,
        reading_t<RT> const & ... readings) {
    strcat(buf, reading.name);
    strcat(buf, ", ");
    concat_readings(buf, readings...);
    return buf;
}

int main() {
    static reading_t<float> longitude = {"Longitude", "%f", "deg", 0.0};
    static reading_t<uint32_t> altitude = {"Altitude", "%d", "m", 0};
    static reading_t<float> heading = {"Heading", "%f", "deg", 0};

    char buf[256] = {};
    concat_readings(buf, longitude, altitude, heading);
    printf("%s", buf);
}
```

Output:

```
Longitude, Altitude, Heading
```

---

By mistake first I implemented malloc/free variant of your function, missread your question. So providing this first implementations below just for example.

Assuming that you can use malloc/free, otherwise implement memory allocation your own way, I used malloc/free just for example.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVNNb4MwDL3zK6xOnaBlqNuObZF222GnqrdpqkIINFIIEZhJ1cRv75wSKP3iAPGz/exnB27MC1dM58fjk9RcNamAFa8xVTKJvUtIlldIJXV@E6Qx9jwUhVEMCcODEZoVAraxRxkNR6gEo7B8h/DnAT281DUC37MKZjZ0eYNmBd6CjZZYL70TvoVfphrKbAno3DaWM9y5arUf9OU6d2JgDb41ZkHBlCq5/xp0VRLzvfgh76IzK4FNpQkl@rvSNiEM5yiKYENaHzQxaF9tYqfmuR9ICCPv9uy2lD3BlQhkUlGjD6rUlOkk0VocX2ITaBNK6D4usp0HJGLksswu9/HAiGtus@bQj46yuTn4iRnEdORnL8OTd8SfVUKM613O23ZeMKmH/dXIUPLRrDJVMoxBlTqXaC/iGv4mX701CWEyzew7FTl9FtGiXd4naqjW@9uOuJjCM9WHM05MqX0XlucRi2tn3wEnhs/ufNNK667vxWW5s89BWjh0FvYF3NAM/YyY@ZNpTcRd/ni8A9J6x@M/)

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdint>

template <typename T>
struct reading_t {
    const char *name;
    const char *fmt;
    const char *units;

    T value;
};

char * concat_readings() {
    char * bp = (char*)malloc(1);
    bp[0] = 0;
    return bp;
}

template <typename R, typename ... RT>
char * concat_readings(reading_t<R> const & reading, reading_t<RT> const & ... readings) {
    char * tail = concat_readings(readings...);
    int const bl = strlen(reading.name), tl = strlen(tail);
    char * bp = (char*)malloc(bl + tl + 1);
    strcpy(bp, reading.name);
    strcat(bp, tail);
    free(tail);
    return bp;
}

int main() {
    static reading_t<float> longitude = {"Longitude", "%f", "deg", 0.0};
    static reading_t<uint32_t> altitude = {"Altitude", "%d", "m", 0};
    static reading_t<float> heading = {"Heading", "%f", "deg", 0};

    char * concat = concat_readings(longitude, altitude, heading);
    printf("%s", concat);
    free(concat);
}
```

Output:

```
LongitudeAltitudeHeading
```

Comment: The OP wants *out << buffer; // Longitude, Altitude, Heading*

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for pointing that out! Just modified my question to use buffer instead of malloc/free.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks Arty!

Comment: @maxmclau Welcome! :)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly... and if you want to use a `printf()` like format... I suppose you're looking something as (given that you tagged C++14)

```
template <typename ... Args>
char * concat_readings (char * buffer, Args const & ... as)
 {
   using unused = int[];

   char * b { buffer };

   (void)unused { 0, (std::sprintf(b,
      std::string{"%s "}.append(as.fmt).append(" %s; ").c_str(),
      as.name, as.value, as.units), b+=std::strlen(b), 0)... };

   return buffer;
 }
```

If you can use C++17, you can simplify it a little:

```
template <typename ... Args>
char * concat_readings (char * buffer, Args const & ... as)
 {
   char * b { buffer };

   ((std::sprintf(b,
      std::string{"%s "}.append(as.fmt).append(" %s; ").c_str(),
      as.name, as.value, as.units), b+=std::strlen(b)), ... );

   return buffer;
 }
```

Calling

```
char buffer[520];

concat_readings(buffer, longitude, altitude, heading);

std::cout << buffer << '\n';
```

you get

```
Longitude 0.000000 deg; Altitude 0 m; Heading 0.000000 deg;
```

Obviously, if you can't use `std::string`, `std::strlen()` and `std::sprintf()`, you have to substitute them with something equivalent.

Comment: This is a great solution as well! I love that you've managed to keep it all together. Is that `(void)unused` a pack expansion?

Comment: @maxmclau - yes... `unused` is a variable (an array) and initializing it (inside `{ ... }') you can expand the template pack. Observe that, in the C++17 version, you don't need it because you can use [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold).